# How to define a type parameter that can be either a type or a container for that type?

Tags: scala, generics, containers

I want to define a class like this:

```
class MyClass[C,X](
  val states: C,
  val transform: C => X
)
```

But `X` can only be equals to `C` or a container for `C`, like `List[C]` or `Set[C]` -- it does not make sense for the problem at hand if `X` is defines as anything else.

Is there a way to impose this restriction in Scala?

Comment: From your comment to my answer, it looks as if you are trying to enumerate extensionally all the types for which you think the construction works, instead of intensionally specifying the required properties of the type constructor `F[X]` that can then be replaced by `List[X]`, `Set[X]`, or `Id[X]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

class MyClass[C, F[_]](
                       val states: C,
                       val transform: C => F[C]
                      )

type Id[A] = A

new MyClass[Int, Set](1, Set(_)) // Set[Int] is a container for Int
new MyClass[String, List]("a", List(_)) // List[String] is a container for String
new MyClass[Boolean, Id](true, x => x) // Id[Boolean] is Boolean itself
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Assuming XY-problem. Now this posting has two answers:

1. The cumbersome solution that relies on subclassing
2. Typeclass-based solution that probably solves the actual `X`

---

**Subclassing-solution**

If you run

```
List(List(0), Set(0))
```

in the interpreter, you will see that `List` and `Set` unify only at `Iterable`.

Thus, the most specific restriction you can make is:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

class MyClass[C, Container[X] <: collection.immutable.Iterable[X]] (
  val states: C,
  val transform: C => Container[C]
)
```

I wouldn't advise to make it *this* generic though. If in doubt, take `List` first, generalize later only if it's *actually* necessary.

---

**Typeclass-solution**

From your comment, it looks as if it's an XY-problem, and what you actually want is a type constructor `F` with an appropriate type-class.

Define your type-class first, for example with the constraint that one sholud be able to iterate through `F`:

```
trait MyTC[F[_]] {
  def hasIterator[X](fx: F[X]): Iterator[X]
}
```

Then define `MyClass` for arbitrary `F` for which there is an instance of the typeclass:

```
class MyClass[X, F[_] : MyTC] {
  val states: X
  val transform: X => F[X]
}
```

Then simply define instances of `MyTC` for `List`, `Set`, or `Id`:

```
implicit object ListMyTC extends MyTC[List] {
  def hasIterator[X](lx: List[X]): Iterator[X] = lx.iterator
}

type Id[X] = X
implicit object ListMyTC extends MyTC[Id] {
  def hasIterator[X](x: X): Iterator[X] = Iterator(x)
}
```

And then you can use `MyClass` with `List`s or with `Id`:

```
val m1 = new MyClass[Int, List] { ... } // Integer states, transforms to List
val m2 = new MyClass[String, Id] { ... } // String-labeled states, transforms to other `String`
```

etc.

The idea is essentially to replace your attempt to extensionally enumerate all the container types for which you think your construction might work by an intensional definition, that accepts any `F` that can prove that it satisfies all the requirements in `MyTC` by providing an instance of `MyTC[F]`.

Comment: The problem is that the type can also be `C` itself.

Comment: @Jeff Unification of `Iterable[X]` and `X` is something like `Any`. Looks like XY-problem to me. Are you sure that you don't want to allow a functor `F[_]` and `transform` of type `C => F[C]`? Don't enumerate all the classes for which you *think* your construction could work (`X`, `List[X]`, `Set[X]`). Instead, specify the *properties* that the type constructor `F[X]` should have.

Comment: @Jeff I've updated my answer with a solution that works for `List[X]`, `Set[X]`, or just `X` (that is, `Id[X]`).